# How to delete existing monitor display settings

Tags: mac, display, resolution

For my setup, I have the macbook I use for work hooked up to both my 75" Samsung TV that I use as my primary monitor and a secondary 1080P monitor on a monitor arm next to me on the couch. This has worked great for me for a couple years now, but as of yesterday the settings for my secondary monitor have somehow seem to have completely overwritten the settings. This is to the point where I believe the EDID for my secondary monitor has completely overwritten the EDID for my Samsung TV. When I looked at my display settings previously I had one display labeled "SAMSUNG" with a default resolution of 4k and one labeled "VG2448" with a default resolution of 1080p, but now when I look at my display settings I just see two "VG2448" displays both with a default resolution of 1080p:
[image]

The result of this being that the Samsung display always defaults to the 1080p resolution and the display goes black shortly after turning on. I've tried resetting the NVRAM, resetting the SEC, and removing any `com.apple.windowserver(UUID).plist` I can find in my `/Library/Preferences` folder. I looked in the `/Library/Preferences/ByHost` folders but couldn't find any `com.apple.preference.displays.[long number].plist` files to delete. The only `/Library` folder I couldn't check was the one for the sysadmin user for the device. All of this has been to no avail as the displays continue to remain exactly the same in the settings.

I have my personal Windows PC hooked up to both displays as well and it still recognizes the TV as "SAMSUNG" with the proper resolutions, so I don't think anything has been corrupted on the part of the TV. Short of factory resetting my Macbook, is there any course of action available to me to try and reset the settings for these displays to what they were before?